# Erlang relx: add appmon but told application already started

Tags: erlang, release, relx

I try add appmon in [ranch example](https://github.com/ninenines/ranch/tree/master/examples/tcp_echo),  here is my relx.config file

```
{paths, ["/usr/local/lib"]}.
{release, {tcp_echo_example, "1"}, [
   tcp_echo,
   appmon
]}.
{extended_start_script, true}.
```

After generated, I start application succeed but failed start appmon in Erlang console

```
(tcp_echo_example@127.0.0.1)3> application:start(appmon). 
{error,{already_started,appmon}}
```

Looks appmon already started, but how can I see the appmon window?

Erlang: R16B02
relx: 1.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Appmon is already started and there is no need to start it again.

Also you can use:

```
%% OTP >= R16B01
ok = application:ensure_started(App)
```

or something like

```
case application:start(App) of
    ok -> ok;
    {error, {already_started, App}} -> ok
end
```

to ensure run the application.

Comment: Yes, it already started, but how can I see the appmon window?